# i cant read the env variables on my ecs task

Tags: docker, express, amazon-ecs, ecs-taskdefinition

i have this code on my webpack.config.js file

```
const environment = process.env.ENVIRONMENT;
const uridb = `mongodb+srv://admin:admin@development-db.${process.env.URI}.mongodb.net/development?retryWrites=true&w=majority`
```

and inside my task definition you can see that the env do exist
[image]

but when i see the logs on my container i get undefined

> MONGO_CONNECTION_STRING mongodb+srv://admin:admin@development-db.undefined.mongodb.net/development?retryWrites=true&w=majority

how do i make my envs reachable?

Answer (score 0):

Your Webpack config file is something that is used at build time. Webpack is a build tool. You need to move that `${process.env.URI}` environment variable lookup into your actual application code so that it can be resolved at run-time.